# Getting "TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'" when searching for string on web page

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, urllib2

I'm using Python 3.7 and Django.  I want to search for a string in an HTML page.  I tried this ...

```
req = urllib2.Request(article.path, headers=settings.HDR)
html = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=settings.SOCKET_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS).read()
is_present = html.find(token_str) >= 0
```

but this is resulting in an error

```
TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'
```

complaining about the last line, where I do the "find."  What's the right way to search for a string in HTML?

Comment: Can you print the contents of `html`?  You can do `html.decode('utf8').find(token_str)...` but there may be a better way depending on what the output looks like. (Note you would be better off reading the headers to know the decoding type).

Answer (score 1):

Dave!

For pulling data out of HTML files, I really recommend the library `Beautiful Soup`. For now, you could just be searching for that token within all the tags of the HTML file, but, at some other time, you might be looking for more complex things such as finding a piece of string thats only within a certain paragraph tag. To install it with pip:

`pip install beautifulsoup4`

For your case, here's a tested snippet that can solve your problem. It uses a simple regexp pattern for the token that you are looking for. If there's a match for that token inside an HTML tag, it returns True. Otherwise, False.

I hope this function can help you getting started with `Beautifulsoup`. It's a really powerful library.

```py
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Here goes somet title
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p class="title">
   <b>
    Hello World!
   </b>
  </p>
  <p class="class1">
   Once upon a time..... there was a my_token here....
   <a class="token" href="http://example.com/token" id="link1">
  </p>

  <p class="class2">
   Nope....
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
"""


def search_inside_whole_html_tags_for(html_doc, str_lookup):
    """
    Looks for a str_lookup using a simple regexp pattern. Returns
    True if the str_lookup was found in the whole HTML text. Otherwise,
    returns False.
    """
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

    # simple regepx pattern: the fixed str lookup
    rslt = html_soup.find_all(text=re.compile(str_lookup))

    return bool(rslt)


print(search_inside_whole_html_tags_for(html_doc, str_lookup="my_tokenx"))
print(search_inside_whole_html_tags_for(html_doc, str_lookup="my_token"))  # this the token

>>> False
>>> True
```

Comment: Thx.  BeautifulSoup is good for parsing HTML files but I want to know if this string occurs anywhere on the page, regardless of what element it might occur in, whetehr its text or part of an attribute.

Comment: For just looking if that string is anywhere on the html_doc (given that it's a string), maybe just the expression: "my_token" in html_doc could do the trick. But that wouldn't return if it was found in a text or in an attribute.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant to the question! The error that is mentioned is typical in Python 3 and you don't solve it by suggesting the use of a special package! Which, BTW, has nothing to do with the error!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing a string to an integer hence the type error. Need to convert to an integer on the string or test for if not None.

**Test:**

```
>>> token_str = 'test'
>>> token_str >= 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
>>> token_str != None
True
```

**Recommended Solution:**

`is_present = html.find(int(token_str)) >= 0`

or

`is_present = html.find(token_str) != None`